# class definition inside a class?

Tags: python, django-forms

```
class ItemForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ['added_by']
```

i can not understand what this piece of code is doing .i understood that ItemForm is  inheriting Modelform but then a class definition inside a class ??

The Item class is  :

```
class Item(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    quantity = db.IntegerProperty(default=1)
    target_price = db.FloatProperty()
    priority = db.StringProperty(default='Medium',choices=[
      'High', 'Medium', 'Low'])
    entry_time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    added_by = db.UserProperty()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta is a special class definition.

In this example, it is a simple inheritance model. ModelForm creates a form based on a Model class, so via giving a class definiton to ModelForm class, it creates the form elements according to related Model class definiton.

Answer (score 3):

It's part of Django's magic. The metaclass for `ModelForm` (among other classes) looks for an inner `Meta` class and uses it to make various changes to the outer class. It's one of the deeper parts of Python that most people will never have to deal with first-hand.

Comment: is it the dreaded meta class of python we are talking about or is Meta here just another class name and it happens to be Meta ?

Comment: Meta in this case has nothing to do with Pythons meta classes.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can define classes within other classes as a way of encapsulating the inner class. The way Django is using this is actually quite excellent.

See this link for more info: http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/64739

Comment: The linked article is more relevant to Java.  In python, the nested class doesn't get any special privileges, just a different home.